# Guidebook for Hiking activities around Geneva

Tags: hiking, camping, trekking, europe, books

Any recommendations for good hiking books describing trails, camp sites (back- and front-country), etc. along with their topology, difficulty levels for Switzerland, especially around Geneva? Something in English would be really great.

Comment: When I edited your question to add the [europe] tag, the site suggested a tag about [european long distance trails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_long-distance_paths), which seems like it might be a useful topic to explore. Long-distance trails are usually well-documented in guidebook form. It looks like trails E1, E4 and E5 all pass through Switzerland.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely a good place to start looking. I will try and find if I can find more detailed references for them and add them here if I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swiss Alpine Club (SAC-CAS) has [a colletion of guide books](https://www.sac-cas.ch/de/shop/buecher/) however only few are available in English.

SAC also has [Tour Portal](https://www.sac-cas.ch/en/huts-and-tours/sac-route-portal/) available in English with almost 1800 tours categorized by type (hiking, climbing, ski touring, via ferrata) and difficulty.
I personally find it to be the best resource about trails and tours in Switzerland.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this post on glocals.com where someone shared their travel guide through Google maps (https://drive.google.com/open?id=17gleDabcsxBwTrxR2wxUwc17f8QAj8GH&usp=sharing). It has some suggestions for hikes.